# Where is the "boot camp directory" in a Windows installation?

Tags: windows-7, installation, boot-camp

I think this should be a simple question, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I'm trying to do a Boot Camp Windows 7 install on a old Black Macbook, and I've gotten to the point of installing the drivers. The guide says:

> Insert the CD or DVD or connect the external disk with the Windows support software.
>   The installer may start automatically. If it doesn’t, do one of the following:
>
> If the support software is on the same USB flash drive as the Windows 7 installer, 
>   double-click the setup.exe file in the WindowsSupport directory.
>
> Otherwise, double-click the setup.exe file in the Boot Camp directory.

I can find the WindowsSupport directory, but I have a separate Windows 7 Install disk, so presumably this doesn't apply to me. Where's the Boot Camp directory?

Comment: It's usually on the OSX Install DVD, at one point in time there was a separate "Windows Driver Disk" that was required.

Answer (score 1):

Once Windows is installed boot into Windows and load either your OSX Install DVD (there is a separate partition that is visible in Windows that contains the drivers), or if it's a newer OS X then it's probably on that support USB. Mac isn't really enterprise friendly and doesn't just dump the drivers files on an ftp repo somewhere, unfortunately.